# Need Variable Numbers of Isolated Docker-based Applications with Distinct Public IPs from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

Does anyone know the correct AWS services needed to launch multiple instances of a Docker image on unique publicly accessible IP addresses?

Every path I have tried with Amazon's ECS seems to be set up for scaling instances locked away in a private network and / or behind a single IP.

The container has instances of a web application running on port 8080, but ideally the end user will connect via port 80.

The objective is to be able to launch around 20 identical copies of the container at once, with each accessible via its own public IP.

There is no need for the public IP to be known in advance, as on startup, I patch the data as needed with the current IP address.

The containers live in Amazon's ECR, and there are a couple of unique instances running in standalone EC2 machines, I was trying to use ECS to launch multiple instances at will, but can successfully launch a total of 1 at a time before getting errors about conflicting ports because things are not isolated enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with ECS:

1. Change your task definition to use the [awsvpc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-networking.html) networking mode.
2. Change your [service network configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service_definition_parameters.html#sd-networkconfiguration) to auto-assign a public IP.

If you're deploying onto EC2 instances, I think you may be limited in the number of either network interfaces or public IP addresses that you can use. Fargate does not have this restriction.